# How to control interval between kubernetes cronjobs (i.e. cooldown period after completion)

Tags: kubernetes, cron, kubernetes-cronjob

If I set up a [kubernetes cronjob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) with for example

```
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
```

then it will create a job every 5 minutes.

However if the job takes e.g. 4 minutes, then it will create another job 1 minute after the previous job completed.

Is there a way to make it create a job every 5 minutes *after* the previous job finished?

You might say; just make the schedule `*/9 * * * *` to account for the 4 minutes the job takes, but the job might not be predictable like that.

Comment: I don't think it's achievable with `CronJobs`. Could you tell what exactly do you want to achieve with this `Job`? Maybe there is other solution based on what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no possibility within Kubernetes `CronJob` to specify a situation when the timer starts  (for example 5 minutes) after a job is completed.

A word about `cron`:

> The software utility **cron** is a time-based [job scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_scheduler) in [Unix-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like) computer [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system). Users that set up and maintain software environments use cron to schedule jobs (commands or [shell scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script)) to run periodically at **fixed times, dates, or intervals.**
>
> --  *[Wikipedia.org: Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)*

The behavior of your `CronJob` within Kubernetes environment can be modified by:

- As said `Schedule` in `spec` definition

  ```sh
    schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  ```
- [startingDeadline](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#starting-deadline) field that is optional and it describe a deadline in seconds for starting a job. If it doesn't start in that time period it will be counted as failed. After a 100 missed schedules it will no longer be scheduled.
- [Concurrency policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#concurrency-policy) that will specify how concurrent executions of the same `Job` are going to be handled:

  - Allow - concurrency will be allowed
  - Forbid - if previous `Job` wasn't finished the new one will be skipped
  - Replace - current `Job` will be replaced with a new one
- [Suspend](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#suspend) parameter if it is set to `true`, all subsequent executions are suspended. This setting does not apply to already started executions.

You could refer to official documentation: [CronJobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/)

As it's unknown what type of `Job` you want to run you could try to:

- Write a shell script in type of:

```sh
    while true
    do
      HERE_RUN_YOUR_JOB_AND_WAIT_FOR_COMPLETION.sh
      sleep 300 # ( 5 * 60 seconds ) 
    done
```

- Create an image that mimics usage of above script and use it as pod in Kubernetes.
- Try to get logs from this pod if it's necessary as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#basic-logging-in-kubernetes)

Another way would be to create a pod that could [connect to Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#programmatic-access-to-the-api).

Take a look on additional resources about `Jobs`:

- [Kubernetes.io: Fine parallel processing work queue](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/fine-parallel-processing-work-queue/)
- [Kubernetes.io: Coarse parallel processing work queue](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/coarse-parallel-processing-work-queue/)

Please let me know if you have any questions to that.